# Page Navigation in php...showing same content as was before reload

Tags: php, layout, web, navigation

I have a web page with the following layout:

```
Navigation Pane         --------------content pane---------------
item1                   -                                       -
item2                   -                                       -
item3                   -                                       -
item4                   -                                       -
item5                   -----------------------------------------
```

So when i click on item1 the content pane shows content related to item 1
and so on. I am using `$.post()` to retrieve data.

The problem is when i reload the page with a particular item selected, i will be
shown the content related to the default selected item for the page(say item1).
How should i implement so that when i reload the page i am shown the content 
corresponding to the previously selected item.

This is the same as the facebook's nav pane for navigating through groups and news feed.

Please Help me out here..

Comment: What have you already tried? Show us some code.

Comment: You can use `#item1` on item links, and check `location.hash` on page load.

Comment: I want to implement it like FB. My files are in different directories.
and i want to change the url too. Plz take a look at fb's nav pane.

Comment: @RichardA :The things i have mentioned above is tried by me. I just want to display same content on reload as displayed before.

Comment: what do u mean by refresh with a particular item selected?Do u mean that on refreshing page after selecting (suppose) #item3,u want content related to #item3 displayed and not the default content(say #item1)

Comment: @Mayur: yes i want the same

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

Add a hash tag to the links:

```
<a href="#item1">item1<a>
<a href="#item2">item2<a>
...etc
```

When the page reloads, check the hash tag and load the relevant content:

```
loadMyContent(window.location.hash) //where loadMyContent is your own function
```

Since you refused to post code (you should always post code), I'm just trying to demonstrate the general idea. It would need to be edited to be compatible with your project. You might also want to do some sanitisation on the `window.location.hash` to avoid JS errors with non-existent items.

Answer (score 0):

have an index.php as your controller page with following code

```
$action=$_GET['status'];
switch($action)
{
     case 'item1': include_once "item1_content.php";break;
     case 'item2': include_once "item2_content.php";break;
     default : include_once "default_page.php";break;

}
```

next,the individual nav bar links sud be like the following

```
<a href="index.php?status=item1">item1</a>
<a href="index.php?status=item2">item2</a>
<a href="index.php">Link to default content</a>
```

what basically happens is that whenever u click on a link,u will be redirected to index page along with status flag set and based on the status flag,appropriate content will be displayed. Secondly,since the url has the status set even on refresh,there won't be a redirection to default content.

Hope it helps..!!

Comment: However if u come to index.php from a different page,since status flag is not set,u will get default content.

Comment: BUT This would cause the whole page to load. I just want the content pane to load when user clicks on the items

Comment: although i have not tried this method before but i guess you can achieve what you want by making ajax call on each individual links to alter a div element that will display your content.And then,to solve your refresh problem you can probably have a second flag that holds the current content status and pass that variable in ur anchor tag href. And in the index page have a check on the second flag to determine the content after refresh. Seems quite a lot of if-else's.. :)